# using localtime on a date

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a column in my SQLite database that stores time values in UTC. How do i get the count of distinct days?

The below gives a result based on the UTC days, which would be wrong in the local timezone :

```
select distinct(date(column)) from table
```

The below would consider the time as well, which would be wrong :

```
select distinct(datetime(column,'localtime')) from table
```

Would it make sense to convert the date to localtime as below :

```
select distinct(date(column,'localtime')) from table
```

I am not sure if using the `localtime` conversion on a `date`, as opposed to a `datetime`, has any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference between `date` and `datetime` is in the output format, not in any internal calculations.
(All [five date/time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) behave the same in this regard.)

Comment: thanks. that's interesting. Is this mentioned anywhere in the documentation? I could not find it myself.

Comment: No, except on the page I linked to.